# How to build Phonegap application in release mode using the online Phonegap build service

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

Using the online building service for Phonegap applications [Adobe Phonegap Build Platform](http://build.phonegap.com), I am looking for a way to build the app in release mode. The "enable debugging" feature is disabled but still I keep getting debuggable ".apk" files that are being rejected by Google Play Store upon submission. The config.xml of my Phonegap project does not contain any entries in that matter. Any suggestions? I am clearly looking for way to compile online as I do not want to fiddle around with the Phonegap CLI - just saying to avoid any suggestions like "use CLI-command XYZ"...